# Detect end of playback on lock screen - AVPlayer

Tags: ios, avplayer, mpremotecommandcenter

I've the array of audio file and would like to play them consecutively. Is there any way to detect when AVPlayer ending playing on lock screen so that I could call a completion handler and play next sound? I want to call nextPlayAudio() from my PlayerViewController class. I am fire notification after finishing current playback audio but nextPlayAudio() not get called after finishing.

Comment: can you provide relevant code such as your Notification setup, nextPlayAudio, end-of-playback observers, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime` notification to manage this.

Example as a service here: https://github.com/noreasonprojects/ModernAVPlayer/blob/develop/Sources/Core/Services/PlaybackObservingService.swift
 | Check the PlayingState file, where the service is used.